# read received notification when open app without tapping notification

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I developed an application and used FCM to handle notifications. When the application is in background and a notification received, by clicking on the notification the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is called and everything is ok! but if the app is opened with other ways like tapping on the app icon, the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` function is not called and the notification stays unread.
I know this is how it works but i want whenever there is a notification and no matter how the app opened the  `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` called!

Comment: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions `  check the launching options dictionary  --> What you are looking for

Comment: `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)` method called when we tapped on notification bar in foreground

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364315/how-to-clear-the-remote-notification-in-your-app